# Eclipselink group by is not working

Tags: java, jpa, group-by, eclipselink, criteria-api

How to add `groupBy` criteria to the code below? Because if I add `criteriaQuery.groupBy(from.get(minutis.Preke_.prId));` - I get exactly the same SQL statement (without `groupBy`):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = MinutisManager.getInstance().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(minutis.Preke.class);
Root<minutis.Preke> from = criteriaQuery.from(minutis.Preke.class);
from.fetch(minutis.Preke_.tiekejai, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(minutis.PrekeTiekejas_.tiekejas, JoinType.LEFT);
//criteriaQuery.groupBy(from.get(minutis.Preke_.prId));

TypedQuery<minutis.Preke> typedQuery = MinutisManager.getInstance().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(0);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(100);
typedQuery.getResultList();
```

**EDIT 1:**

`criteriaQuery.distinct(true)` is not an option for me. Because that command hangs the whole statement and if I use `EXPLAIN`:
[image: When distinct is uesd]

If I use `GROUP BY` on the query, then `EXPLAIN` is:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I get this SQL statement with and without `criteriaQuery.groupBy(from.get(minutis.Preke_.prId));`

```
SELECT ... FROM preke t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN preke_tiekejas t0 ON (t0.pr_id = t1.pr_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN tiekejas t2 ON (t2.tiek_id = t0.tiek_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN gamintojas t3 ON (t3.gam_id = t1.gam_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN google_compare t4 ON (t4.pr_id = t1.pr_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN grupe t5 ON (t5.pgs_id = t1.pgs_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN preke_kaina t6 ON (t6.pr_id = t1.pr_id) ORDER BY t1.pr_id LIMIT ?, ?
```

Comment: What are you looking to get?  Using group by and returning an entity is not a great idea, and especially not going to help your fetch join clause - it would corrupt the returned entities and the cache.

Comment: Try turning on ElcipseLink logging to log the SQL it executes as described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: I disabled the cache completely, because I'm using stand alone swing program, not JEE (that's my decision). I need, that Fetch will populate parent entities with children on one query - and that works. Group by is needed, because `Preke` entity has @OneToMany `PrekeTiekejas` entities and I get duplicate rows of `Preke` just different `PrekeTiekejas` fields. My goal is to get single `Preke` entities and populate it's child `@OneToMany PrekeTiekejas` at the same query - single call to database.

Comment: I see SQL statements, and they are the same both times with and without `criteriaQuery.groupBy(from.get(minutis.Preke_.prId));`. The SQL statements are identical both times.

Comment: Does it help adding the select statement `criteriaQuery.select(from)` before grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will file a bug in Eclipselink, because if I change fetch line with QueryHints, everything works:

Change this (with this line I get duplicate Preke entities with populated children entities):

```
from.fetch(minutis.Preke_.tiekejai, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(minutis.PrekeTiekejas_.tiekejas, JoinType.LEFT);
```

To this (with this lines I get unique Preke entities with populated children entities):

```
typedQuery.setHint(QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH, "Preke.tiekejai");
typedQuery.setHint(QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH, "Preke.tiekejai.tiekejas");
```

I get my desired result.

**EDIT 1:**

The bug really exists, now max resulsts is not working. Both cases typedQuery is identical.

```
typedQuery.setMaxResults(100);
System.out.println(typedQuery.getResultList().size()); //prints 73

typedQuery.setMaxResults(500);
System.out.println(typedQuery.getResultList().size()); //prints 413
```

Comment: did you finally filed a bug with eclipselink, I'm having the same problem now, groupBy and maxResults not working together. Thanxs

Comment: To be honest, i don't remember. Sorry about that, it just was long time ago. I know I should have updated my question or answer with created bug link right away, but it is how it is...

Answer (score 1):

The SQL for the GROUP BY query should definitely contain a GROUP BY.  Ensure that you are compiling and deploying the code correctly.

It could be a bug that the group by is ignored, as normal group by queries will not select object, but aggregated values.  Check that you are using the latest release, and perhaps log a bug, or try JPQL.

In general your query does not make any sense, normally on a group by query you can only select the fields that you grouped by, or aggregation functions.

Perhaps consider batch fetching instead of join fetching.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Comment: If I use Batch fetching, the query works and then I don't need Fetch and don't need group by, but performance is decreased compared to GROUP BY statement. I will look into the possibility of bug.

Comment: And the query does the job that I want perfectly (populates parents children , and the speed is perfect), but it returns duplicate `Preke` objects. That is the only problem that I have left.

Answer (score 1):

No problem, I found the bug report, here it is, just in case someone else needs it.[Criteria api ignores group by statement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402026)